# Entity Framework Navigation property update

Tags: entity-framework, change-tracking

I use Entity Framework 6 with SQLite and code first.
I have a problem with the update of objects.

I have an "Record" object

```
class Record {

  public long Id;
  public long StatusId

  public virtual Statut Status;
}
```

And so a "Status" object.

I create a Record object like that

```
var newRecord = context.Records.Create();
```

While I did not add it in the context, the Status property is null.

```
context.Records.Add(newRecord);
```

Now, I have a Status object in Status navigation property (The status object with id = 0).

But if I change StatusId with 1 for example (this status id exist), the Status property is not updated.

Entity framework should not detect this kind of change with dynamic proxies?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "default Status"? If that's a non-null `Status` object, how does it get there if you didn't set `Status` nor `StatusId`?

Comment: StatusId is not nullable so by default its value is 0. And in my database I have a status object with 0 as Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observe is caused by Entity Framework's *relationship fixup* mechanism, a process that's triggered by many EF methods and that takes care of consistency of foreign key values and references (among others).

Relationship fixup is triggered by a pretty large [number of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692612/861716), but `DbSet.Create()` is not one of them. So here's what happens:

```
var newRecord = context.Records.Create();
```

A new `Record` is created, having `StatusId` = 0. No relationship fixup.

```
context.Records.Add(newRecord);
```

The new record is attached to the context. Now EF does execute relationship fixup. If you monitor SQL, you will see that a `Status` record is fetched from the database.

```
newRecord.StatusId = 1;
```

No EF method is executed: no relationship fixup, the `Status` object is still the one with `Id` = 0.

What you can do now to get the right `Status` record into `newRecord` is either execute one of the methods that trigger relationship fixup, or call `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calling DetectChanges seems heavy. Why proxies don't make this work in setter ?

Comment: Because in most cases you don't need this. Recommended way to work with EF is create context - do stuff - save - dispose context. And then, `StatusId` is not overridden, so a proxy can't do anything with its setter.

Comment: When I read documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx   in "Synchronizing the changeds between ths FKs and Navigation properties" I understand that Entity framework should make it for POCO entities with proxies.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely correct what they say there. If you change a primitive property like `StatusId` there is *no way* that DetectChanges can be triggered.